# Pillow will not import

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am using a plain install of python on windows
I've installed the Pillow library with `pip install Pillow` and I am unable to import it whether I use `import Image` or `from PIL import Image` or `import Pillow`, all it returns is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

When I try to intall Pillow again it returns the following which tells me it is already installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\isaac\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (6.2.1)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow via pip 19.3.1 and easy install.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Last night I had a dream that I was eating a giant marshmallow. When I woke up, I couldn't find my pillow. Boom, boom, thanks for listening, I'm here all week :-) More seriously, you may want to check that the python you're pipping into is the same as the one you're running. I've had problems like this with modern venv-style environments with their plethora of different versions running alongside each other.

Comment: Try running the following commands and pasting the output into your question `which pip`, `which python`, `pip -V` and `python -V`

Comment: Make sure you are calling your script using python 3 and not 2 (python3 main.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using? Pycharm, anaconda, or just plain install of python?

If you are using Pycharm or another progam that uses venv (virtual environments) then you must ensure you are downloading the library to the venv you are using for the project. This can be done through using pip inside the folder with the venv or by using pycharms built in import tool.

Plain install of python could be an issue on mac/linux machines. You maybe be using the machines built in system version of python and not using your install of it. If you are using mac/linux ensure you run files via python3 command as Im sure you are using modern python whereas macs current version i think is python2.7 and ubuntu uses 2.7 as well i believe. So if you were to run files via just python in command line you use the 2.7 version but if you use the python3 command you will use your fresh install of python!

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I am using a plain install of python on windows

Comment: Nvm It was a python3 problem, It started working and I don't know why

Comment: fair enough. Id suggest if you are going to do a decent amount of work with python, use Pycharm. For me its better to have a full ide with all the functionality you will ever need. If you do go this route, watch youtube video or 2 to properly setup pycharm as initiall setup can be tricky if you dont know what you are doing!

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently not using pycharm because I have never had much luck with virtual envs